# How to query a json array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing

How to parse the below example json and create another json where name is allen or tom or jack.
The names can occur any number of times.

```js
{
  "responseCode": 0,
  "responseMessage": "SUCCESS",
  "data": [{
      "name": "tom",
      "school": "abc",
      "college": "def"
    },
    {
      "name": "harry",
      "school": "abc",
      "college": "def"
    },
    {
      "name": "jack",
      "school": "abc",
      "college": "def"
    },
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "school": "abc",
      "college": "def"
    },
    {
      "name": "allen",
      "school": "abc",
      "college": "def"
    }
    ...
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const data = `{
    "responseCode": 0,
    "responseMessage": "SUCCESS",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "tom",
            "school": "abc",
            "college": "def"
        },
        {
            "name": "harry",
            "school": "abc",
            "college": "def"
        },
        {
            "name": "jack",
            "school": "abc",
            "college": "def"
        },
        {
            "name": "tom",
            "school": "abc",
            "college": "def"
        },
        {
            "name": "allen",
            "school": "abc",
            "college": "def"
        }
    ]
}`

const dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
const filteredResults = dataObject.data.filter(function (entry) {
    return ['tom', 'jack', 'allen'].indexOf(entry.name) !== -1
})
console.log(filteredResults);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow! You can make your answers more useful by adding some explanation instead of posting code only annotated with "try this".